# how to configure gnome to use only one specific keyboard layout on lock screen?

Tags: gnome, lockscreen, keyboard-layout

for lock screen, gnome uses keyboard layout that was last used before locking the screen. Is there a possibility to configure gnome in such a way that it will always switch keyboard layout to some specific value for lock screen?

Example, how it works now: You have two layouts configured, `en` and `abc`. You've been entering some text using keyboard layout `abc` and then locked the screen by hitting Meta + L or placing your computer into sleep mode. Reaching lock screen, you find your keyboard layout is `abc`. You switch it to `en` and enter your password, unlock the screen and see that your active gnome desktop keyboard layout is `abc`.

Desired: You have two layouts configured, `en` and `abc`. You've been entering some text using keyboard layout `abc` and then locked the screen by hitting Meta + L or placing your computer into sleep mode. Reaching lock screen, you find your keyboard layout is `en`, because you managed to somehow configure gnome (or use some lock screen activation scripts/hooks?) to always switch to `en` for lock screen. Desktop keyboard layout after unlocking could be retained (`abc`), but this is of no importance in scope of given question.

Answer (score 2):

found it!

Gnome Settings → Region & Language → Input sources section. Click on the «Login screen» button to modify input sources relevant to Login screen. The button itself resides on the window decoration bar and is "hidden openly", hard to find visually.

Comment: Gnome 3.36.3, no such button. 
Anybody knows where they've moved it?

Comment: ubuntu? This dialog seems to look different on ubuntu and manjaro. Wonder if either of these distros modifies gnome standard control center

Comment: This works for the *login* screen, but *does not* for the lock screen, which “inherits” its settings from the main Gnome settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [g3kb-switch](https://github.com/lyokha/g3kb-switch) to control current keyboard layout in GNOME from command line. To change keyboard layout to English on Lock Screen automatically, you can use a script (put it in GNOME autostart):

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver" |
  while read MSG; do
    MSG_STAT=`echo $MSG | grep boolean | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [[ "$MSG_STAT" == "true" ]]; then
      echo "Screen locking actions"
      gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/g3kbswitch/G3kbSwitch --method org.g3kbswitch.G3kbSwitch.Set 0
    fi
  done
```

GNOME disables all extensions on Lock Screen activation for security reasons. So, you need to remove everything from `disable()` method in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/g3kb-switch@g3kb-switch.org/extension.js` as written [here](https://github.com/lyokha/g3kb-switch/issues/8), then reboot.

Comment: what a wonderful solution to a super annoying problem! 
please note, that according to stackoverflow.com/a/75858699/3157795, you don't need to amend the `extension.js` code, but you can simply add `unlock-dialog` to array `session-modes` of `metadata.json`.
it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gnome extension, which resets keyboard layout when screensaver activates. You can access it on https://github.com/galets/gnome-keyboard-reset